# Firefox form submit with target="_blank"

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox

I'm developing a Struts2 web app and I have an issue with firefox. If I test the same function with Chrome, it works perfectly, but with firefox nothing happens. Let me explain what I do:

a jQuery function creates the form (`wrapper` is a container in my page, and `myValue` depends on the user request):

```
var form = $('<form/>', {action: 'myAction', target= '_blank'});
var hiddenInput = $('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name= 'reportId', value= myValue});

myWrapper.append(form.append(hiddenInput));
form.submit();
```

When I submit the form Struts2 creates a report using Jasper and in the new tab the PDF document opens.

But in Firefox I see the form submission, I see that Struts2 generates the PDF, but the new tab doesn't open. I'm developing under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Firefox version is 46.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and got around it by appending the form to the document and then removing it after submit.

```
var testHTML = angular.element('<form id="testForm" target="_blank" action="something.html" method="post" <input type="hidden" name="FirstName"/>');

angular.element(document.body).append(testHTML);
testHTML.submit();
angular.element(testHTML).remove();
```